# Display image in picture box from SQL Server in vb.net winforms

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

In a table `image` column is storing as 0xFF...how to display this format file in picture box in vb.net winforms? I tried below code but not working and showing readtimeout/writetimeout error ..help me..advanced thanks..

```
Private Sub DisplayNameAttribute_UserImage()    
    Try
       strimage = "SELECT userimage from MKBLOGIN where empcode='" & str_empcode & "'"   
       imagedatabytes = objcommonvalidation.func_loadUserImage(strimage)    
       mem = New MemoryStream(imagedatabytes)    
       PictureBox1.Image = ToImage(imagedatabytes)       
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
 End Sub

 Public Function func_loadEmpImage(ByVal str_query As String) As Byte()
     Try
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(str_query, con)
        da.Fill(ds)

        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            data = New Byte(0) {}
            data = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("userimage")
        End If

        Return data.ToArray()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return data.ToArray()
    End Try
End Function

Public Shared Function ToImage(Data As Byte()) As Image
    If Data Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If
    Dim img As Image
    Using stream As New MemoryStream(Data)
        Using temp As Image = Image.FromStream(stream)
            img = New Bitmap(temp)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return img
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 cmd = New SqlCommand("Select userimage from table", con)
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
 dr.read

 Dim ImgStream As New IO.MemoryStream(CType(sqldr("userimage"), Byte()))
 PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ImgStream)
 ImgStream.Dispose()
```

Comment: its not displaying

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim stream As New IO.MemoryStream
    Dim img() As Byte
    img = table.Rows(0)(1)
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(img)
    pddraw.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    conn.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
```

this is only for display not for editing